# Cómo cambio de color la propiedad Background de un Border que forma parte del DataTemplate de un Listbox al ser seleccionado

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tengo este código:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ventana,Path=Listado}"
                 Name="Lista">
            
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Border Width="10"
                                Height="40"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                Background="{Binding Color}"
                                
                                >
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                                            Value="Calibri" />
                                </Style>
                            </StackPanel.Resources>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"
                                       Foreground="Gray"
                                       FontSize="13"
                                       />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValorEnergetico}"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       FontSize="18"
                                       />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

He modificado los items de un ListBox para que me aparezca algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que al seleccionar un item, cualquiera, el elemento Border cambiara a un color negro, por ejemplo. He probado con los DataTrigger aplicándolos al mismo Border, pero me los cambia todos, no el que selecciono.

He conseguido hacerlo con este código utilizando el ControlTemplate del ItemContainerStyle, pero a pesar de que funciona, me da que no está bien hecho.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Border Width="10"
                                            Height="40"
                                            CornerRadius="5"
                                            Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                            Background="{Binding Color}"
                                            Name="borde">
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                                                        Value="Calibri" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"
                                                   Foreground="Gray"
                                                   FontSize="13" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValorEnergetico}"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   FontSize="18" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                             Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="borde"
                                                Property="Background"
                                                Value="Black" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

¿Alguien me puede asesorar si se puede mejorar este código?

Comment: Yo no veo problema, quizás el detalle es que no es reutilizable...pero si ese listbox no habría problema. Existe algo en especifico que te genere duda?